# Two out ot three/four clients fail in using ssh key

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a problem establishing a connection to a remote linux machine from a Windows 10 Pro notebook. I normally use password-less SSH connection and this is the first time I encounter this problem: I have no ideas on how to solve.

I received a private key `id_rsa` (OpenSSH private key) for a machine running linux.

On windows I get this:

- the connection is not established when using the Termius client, that has never given me a single problem with dozens of hosts;
- the connection is not established using `ssh` from the bash terminal on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
- the connection is established using Windows Terminal Version: 1.14.1962.0
- I am able to establish a password-less SSH connectio to the remote server using Visual Studio Code.

When I use `ssh` on WSL, I get these messages:

```
$-> file id_rsa
id_rsa: OpenSSH private key

$-> file id_rsa.pub
id_rsa.pub: OpenSSH RSA public key

$-> ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa
3072 SHA256:REMOVED user@remote-machine (RSA)

$-> ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub
3072 SHA256:REMOVED user@remote-machine (RSA)

$-> ssh user@111.222.333.444 -v -i id_rsa
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for 111.222.333.444
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 111.222.333.444[111.222.333.444] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 111.222.333.444:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:oGg/GNvtgLO8YHaoU+rKdzDo8sTqY9OCwso9crQD7Ac
debug1: Host '111.222.333.444' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:[REMOVED]
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xtXTMKUvn01g28j5YtxT7Y/Gz/Coz4uuyNIjCgmeJBg explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:[REMOVED]
debug1: Server accepts key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:[REMOVED] explicit
Load key "id_rsa": invalid format
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[REMOVED] explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[REMOVED] explicit
Load key "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@111.222.333.444: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The only error message is `invalid format`, but the key has been generated with ssh-keygen and is accepted by Windows Terminal. Furthermore, on the same WSL bash, both `file` and the `ssh-keygen` check pass.

I have also tried to generate other ssh keys, both on the local host and the remote host, but I still get this "pattern" of connectivity.

Is there anyone who can provide a clue on what to look at?

Comment: Did you also receive a matching `id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: I received only the private key. After connecting to the remote host with Powershell, I downloaded also the public key.

Comment: In that case, have you tried _deleting_ any id_rsa.pub files that are near your private-key file? This looks a bit like a key mismatch (where the client offers public key A but signs the challenge using private key B).

Comment: Still working on it. I was able to have the keys working on WSL bash, not yet in Termius. The couple of keys is correct.